# Submit HTML form with GET method with full action path

Tags: php, html, forms, path, get

I am trying to submit a form with method GET and action "index.php?id=3". The problem is that it jumps to the url specified but it cuts off "?id=3" part. I need that so I can identify an user. Any ideas on how I could submit the whole url ? I don't want to change this method, by design is much complex than I told you here. It's a simple version.

Any ideas ? Thanks.

Comment: Why are you using a form with GET?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add a hidden field (`<input type="hidden" name="id" value="3" />`) in the form and use just `index.php` as the action.